# Add custom attribute to sales order address

Tags: magento2, sales-order, address, guest-checkout

I have a custom attribute for customer address which I setup using EAV, I load the custom attribute for customer address using order like this:

```
// Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface
$order = $objectManager>create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')>load($orderId);
$shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
$customerAddressId = $shippingAddress->getCustomerAddressId();
$address = $this->addressRepository->getById($customerAddressId);
$customAttribute = $address->getCustomAttribute();
```

The problem is when the guest makes an order, the guest address was not saved in customer address table. But, it was saved inside `sales_order_address` table, So, that was the problem. I need to make the custom attribute for `sales_order_address`.